# Any other technique for responsive header image

Tags: html, css

all i am new here and i was trying to make responsive header image and to some extent i have done with using this "dislay none "technique

```
#img1{
  display:block;
}
#img2{
  display:none;
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px){
  #img1{
    display:none;
  }
  #img2{
    display:block;
  } 
}
```

so this is the technique that i am using but it doesn't maintain the qualtiy what i think so can you please tell to make a header image responsive that is shorter than this method

thanks in advance

Comment: but what you want to change between the headers?

Comment: i mean i have a header image whos size is 980px but when i open a webpage in bigger screen for example 22inch lcd i want the image to cover the whole width of the screen instead of showing 980px header in the center of the screen(22inch lcd)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use background images?

```
.header {
  background: url(img1.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .header {
    background: url(img2.jpg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Look i have keep the size of the image equals to the screen...i mean  set the image size in photoshop 1980px and i am previewing the webpage on 22inch wide lcd so the so the image is bigger than the screen and it gives a scroll bar at the bottom to move right and left to see the whole image and what i want is that the automatically adjust to the screen size

Comment: well either way, if you use end up using images, then you have to create a property for images that sets max-width:100%. For my example above for the CSS header method, the width of 100% should have you covered. I've also used the background size property of cover to achieve good results using one image across multiple screen sizes.